How can I get a RecommendedFit list for a solution that requires multiple moves for initialization?
I have a timefold process that selects optimal departure times for railcars. The departure times are from 3 locations during each trip, (origin, serving yard, and facility).
I want to use the RecommendedFit functionality to add a rail trip, but each trip adds 3 uninitialized entities to the solution.
I've checked the VRP example code, and can't see how to make it work with multiple new Entities.

You are right - this can not be done with the API. The API was designed to only initialize single entity at a time.
(That is the only way how to make this API provide instantaneous response; once you start assigning multiple entities, the combinatorial nature of the problem starts getting out of hand and therefore no longer meets the design criteria of super-fast responses.)
